# Performance in custom implemented Zooming (ZoomableCanvas)

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawing, 2d

I´m using the ZoomableCanvas class ([ZoomableCanvas)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaelr/2010/07/29/zoomablecanvas/).

XAML:

```
        <ZoomableCanvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="Transparent" ApplyTransform="False" MouseWheel="MyCanvas_MouseWheel" />
```

Now I add 10000 Rectangles to the MyCanvas.Children and to the list of Rectangles recs.

The implemented Scrolling (when ApplyTransform is true) the ZoomableCanvas  provides is evenly, which means height and width of the child-objects change their value.
For my purpose I only want the width of the childs to increase their size when zooming in. The height should not change.
For this purpose i added the following custom behavior.

```
private void MyCanvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Rectangle r in this.recs)
    {     
        r.Width = r.Width + 10;
    }
}
```

This works but is compared to the implemented Zooming super slow. Why is the implemented Zooming so fast and is there a possibilty to achieve my intention to the custom zoom (only affecting width of the objects) in a performant way as well?

Comment: WPF ScaleTransform implementation uses unsafe code and calls milcore api which is the interface between WPF and DirectX. Your code remeasure, rearrange and redraw every Rectangle, the ScaleTransform must manage display on screen directly or something like this

Answer (score 0):

I use also ZoomableCanvas and have the same Problem.
What I have done is improving the **ZoomableCanvas** by replacing Scale dependency property to 2 properties, **ScaleX** and **ScaleY**.
For simplifying improvement.
1. Copy the dependency property Scale and paste twice as ScaleX and ScaleY
2. Delete or comment Scale dependency property
3. Compile and the error report will simplify to find where the old Scale property is used
4. Modify old Scale usages by using ScaleX and ScaleY instead.